# Сделать так, чтобы рамка прилегала к тексту

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы рамка не от левого края до правого была, а облегала текст?

[image: Имеющийся результат]

Comment: Скорее всего элемент с рамкой - блочный. Попробуйте задать ему `display: inline-block` и посмотрите, что из этого выйдет. А вообще, без кода вам здесь не помогут. Картинки мало.

Comment: мне помогло, спасибо за совет, я просто первый раз на этом сайте, прислушаюсь

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "править". Изменения в вопрос стоит вносить именно таким способом.